# Negative Terms in Time Complexity Analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose we have the function below:

```
def foo(n, k):
   for _ in range(n-k):
       for _ in range(n):
           print("bar")
```

If I were to compute the time complexity of this function, I would say that the outer loop will iterates `n-k` times while the inner loop will iterate `n` times for each outer loop iteration. As a result, our print statement, which is `O(1)` runtime, will be executed `n(n-k)` times. Simplified, this number would be `n^2 - nk` times. My question is, then, how do we simplify this expression using big O notation?

I understand that one of the rules of Big O is to eliminate non-dominant terms. In this case, is `-nk` considered non-dominant, since the inputs `n` and `k` will always be non-negative, meaning that the term will always be a negative value? If we believed this to be true, then our simplified Big O would be `O(n^2)`.

However, in cases where there are numerous variables, another rule is to preserve the dominant term for *each* variable. In this case, the only term containing k is the `-nk` term. Therefore, we would preserve this term. If we believed this to be true, then our simplified Big O would be `O(n^2 - nk)`.

Thoughts?

Comment: `O(n^2)` can't be correct since it takes zero time if `n=k`.

Comment: @MichaelCao That looks like you don't know that big-O means upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just drop *-nk* because *n^2* is not necessarily dominant.

*n* and *k* are just two variables. If you know something about them, or their dependence on each other, then and only then can you start making such simplifications.

Perhaps the source of your confusion: If the expression had been *n^2 - n*, then you could indeed drop the *n* term (regardless of its sign) because you **know** that *n^2* is dominant.

Notice however (as maxim1000's answer points out) that big-O represents an *upper bound* for your growth, so you can indeed correctly say it is *O(n^2)* anyway, just as you can say it is *O(n^100)*. But they would not necessarily be the tightest bounds you can express, which can lead to confusion.

Comment: Suppose we knew that n > k for all valid inputs. Would we then be able to deduce that n^2 is the dominant term? Also, does dominant mean the largest value in magnitude or the largest positive term?

Comment: No, *n > k* is not enough to make this assumption. Imagine if *k = n -1* always. Then, your outer loop would always run once, and your time complexity would be *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O is quite close to `<=` relationship. If we have, say, `f(x)=x*(x-y)` where `y` is positive, it's perfectly OK to say that `f(x)<=x^2`. Yes, if `y=x-1`, we can say even more accurate thing - `f(x)<=x`, but that doesn't cancel the previous claim.

`f=O(g)` doesn't mean "f grows with the same speed as g", it means "f doesn't grow faster than g" (see big-Theta notation for the former).

So if `k` is in `[0,n]`, then `n*(n-k)=O(n^2)`. If `k=n-1`, then both `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` are correct.

What happens when you throw `-nk` out is that you lose some information which might allow you to improve you big-O, in exchange you get a simpler formula.

Comment: Very true - I missed mentioning that in my answer. Though in practice big-O is sometimes used like theta, and I suspect OP wanted to express a tightest bound.